# How can I make Emacs scroll horizontally more smoothly?

Tags: emacs, scrolling

I already use `scroll-conservatively` to smooth the vertical scrolling behaviour of Emacs. The horizontal scrolling is still pretty bad. The screen jumps by many columns, and I often lose track of where I am.

Is it possible to make this more smoothly?

Comment: Horizontal scrolling? You are not using `visual-line-mode`?

Comment: Oh no, I dislike that mode. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There appears no direct equivalent of `scroll-conservatively` for horizontal scrolling, but customizing `hscroll-step` (and perhaps also `hscroll-margin`) should produce something at least close to the same behavior. From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Horizontal-Scrolling.html):

> The variable `hscroll-margin` controls how close point can get to the window's left and right edges before automatic scrolling occurs. It is measured in columns. For example, if the value is 5, then moving point within 5 columns of an edge causes horizontal scrolling away from that edge.
>
> The variable `hscroll-step` determines how many columns to scroll the window when point gets too close to the edge. Zero, the default value, means to center point horizontally within the window. A positive integer value specifies the number of columns to scroll by. A floating-point number specifies the fraction of the window's width to scroll by.

Comment: Works perfectly.

Comment: @Arne Excellent! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 6):

This is off-topic to scrolling with my trackpad, but who knows:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-7>") '(lambda ()
                                     (interactive)
                                     (scroll-left 4)))
(global-set-key (kbd "<mouse-6>") '(lambda ()
                                     (interactive)
                                     (scroll-right 4)))
```

If you want to discover what Emacs thinks your horizontal scroll "button" is, try `C-h k` (`describe-key`) and then use your horizontal scroll. So in my current setup, Emacs reports `<mouse-7>` and `<mouse-6>`. I started with `(scroll-left 1)`, but replaced with `4` to get faster scrolling.

Comment: Excellent, I couldn't get `hscroll-step` to take effect, but this works well - thank you.